# Existence of net for Compact Operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be Hilbert spaces and $T:H \to K$ be a compact operator.

> Does there exists nets $e_{\lambda}$ and $f_{\lambda}$ of finite rank operators such that the net $e_{\lambda}f_{\lambda}^*T \in K(H,K)$ converges to $T$ in norm Topology? Here $f_{\lambda}$ denotes adjoint of $f_{\lambda}$ in $K(H,K)$

Since finite rank operators forms approximate identity for compact operators therefore it seems it should be true. Any ideas for proof or counterexample?

Comment: What is $f_\lambda^*$ and why $f_\lambda^*T$ make sense?

Comment: @user10354138  It's just the adjoint of $f_{\lambda}$ and then it's composed with $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and in fact you can choose it to be a sequence.

Since $T$ is compact, $TT^*$ and $T^*T$ are compact self-adjoint, so you get orthogonal eigenspace decomposition with the same eigenvalues (ignoring the kernel which we don't really care here).  Let $e_n=f_n\colon H\to K$ be identifying eigenspaces with eigenvalue $>\frac1n$ via $\frac1{\sqrt{\lambda}}T$ and $0$ on the other eigenspaces, so $e_nf_n^*$ is orthogonal projection onto eigenspaces.  Now it is routine to check $e_nf_n^*T\to T$ in norm.